# How are Lord Ganesh and Aditi related?

Tags: ganesha

How are Lord Ganesh and Aditi the mother of Devas related? Aditi is the mother of Indra and wife of Rishi Kashyap. What relation does she possess with Lord Ganesh?

Comment: I don’t think they have any relation. Could you please cite any source where you came across such a thing?

Comment: Mahotkata avatar is related to her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three ways by Lord Ganesha and Aditi are related:-

1. Aditi was the mother of Lords Indra, Varuna, Surya, Vamana, Rudras and Aditya's. They all are considered to be Deities and Gods. Lord Ganesha himself was a God. **So Aditi is the mother of the fellow companions/Gods of Lord Ganesh.**
2. Aditi is said to have the Trishula/Trident and a divine sword as her weapons. Ganesha was the son of, as we all know, the three eyed Lord Shiva. He also has the famous Trishula. **So we can say that Lord Ganesha,s father and Aditi both have same weapon.**
3. In his Mahotkata vatar Ganesh was born to Sage Kashyap and Aditi in Krita/Satyayuga. **Aditi and Lord Ganesh are related to each other by the Mahotkata avatar/incarnation of Ganesh.**